# A go at 15 with a run

Tags: cribbage

I played a 4, opponent played a six then I played a 5. Easy to count.....3 for run and 2 for the 15. However, what about if it was also a go for me. Do I get one point for the go as well?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would get the go but it could only happen if these are the last 3 cards since it the only way 15 can be a go.